# Integrating Sendgrid into Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

I am trying to send a password reset email with Sendgrid.

Here is the stack trace of the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-
2.5.2\webapp2.py", line 1535, in __call__
    rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-
2.5.2\webapp2.py", line 1529, in __call__
    rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-
2.5.2\webapp2.py", line 1278, in default_dispatcher
    return route.handler_adapter(request, response)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-
2.5.2\webapp2.py", line 1102, in __call__
    return handler.dispatch()
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-
2.5.2\webapp2.py", line 572, in dispatch
    return self.handle_exception(e, self.app.debug)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-
2.5.2\webapp2.py", line 570, in dispatch
    return method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\C\PycharmProjects\alpha\u\user.py", line 121, in post
    response = sg.client.mail.send.post(request_body=mail.get())
  File "C:\Users\C\PycharmProjects\alpha\python_http_client\client.py", 
line 227, in http_request
    return Response(self._make_request(opener, request))
  File "C:\Users\C\PycharmProjects\alpha\python_http_client\client.py", 
line 161, in _make_request
    raise exc
UnauthorizedError
```

I have imported both sendgrid and python-http-client in to my project. (Why should I have to import this separately?)

Here is my test code taken from the Sendgrid demo:

```
class PasswordResetHandler(BaseHandler):
"""
handler to reset the users password.
also to verify if the user email is in the database
"""
def post(self):
    email = self.request.get("email_for_reset")

    sg = sendgrid.SendGridAPIClient(apikey=os.environ.get(SENDGRID_API_KEY))
    from_email = Email("email@example.com")
    to_email = Email(email)
    subject = "Sending with SendGrid is Fun"
    content = Content("text/plain", "and easy to do anywhere, even with Python")
    mail = Mail(from_email, subject, to_email, content)
    response = sg.client.mail.send.post(request_body=mail.get())
    self.redirect('/u/password-reset-confirmation')
```

Can anyone help on what is going on here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax I use is different, using `SendGridClient`:

```
sg = sendgrid.SendGridClient(SENDGRID_API_KEY)

message = sendgrid.Mail(
    to =            to, 
    subject =       subject, 
    html =          html, 
    text =          body, 
    from_email =    sender
)

status, msg = sg.send(message)
```

Comment: Thanks GAEfan, I should have made clear I am trying to integrate the Web API v3. That's the SMTP Relay code, which I have working as well. It's far simpler to integrate into the project.

Answer (score 0):

Check your API key for typos, and to make sure it is loading properly with `os.environ.get()`.

You are getting HTTP error 401. As you can see [in the client.py code](https://github.com/sendgrid/python-http-client/blob/master/python_http_client/client.py) containing `_make_request` on line 161 (and the lines leading up to it), you are getting an HTTPError that is being handled in line 159:

```
exc = handle_error(err)
```

`handle_error()` is implemented [in exceptions.py](https://github.com/sendgrid/python-http-client/blob/master/python_http_client/exceptions.py), and shows that an `UnauthorizedError` comes from HTTPError 401. The most likely cause is a bad api key. Check your api key for typos. I was able to get the same HTTP error by inserting a bad api key into my code. Other than that, I have this functionality working with the same code you showed in the question.

Comment: Thanks for that, I check the api key.

Comment: Try putting SENDGRID_API_KEY in quotes, as shown in the quickstart: https://app.sendgrid.com/guide/integrate/langs/python. So it would look like `sg = sendgrid.SendGridAPIClient(apikey=os.environ.get('SENDGRID_API_KEY'))`